# UIView animation layoutIfNeeded causes top Constraint to break at the start of animation if not called on superview

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, uiviewanimation

I am able to demonstrate the issue with the below simple example code.

I basically have a custom View (sort of like a nav bar) on which I animate the bar to hide/show the blue area (which will contain my buttons).

The problem is that when the animation is occurring to show the blue area, the top constraint of the `menubarContainer` "breaks" for some reason and then fixes itself as the animation finishes.

As you can see in the screenshot, the top constraint "breaks" and then fixes itself again:

[image]

[image]

This seems to be occurring because of the line: `self.layoutIfNeeded()`

If I change that line to `self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()`, then it works fine.

However, calling `layoutIfNeeded` on the `superview` seems to be wasteful as that would layout the entire view controller's view.

Is there any explanation on which view should the `layoutIfNeeded` be called on? Why's it breaking the top constraint if not called on `superview`? Any way to avoid it while also not having to call `layoutIfNeeded` on the entire view controller?

One workaround solution I can think of is to wrap the entire `menubarContainer` in another transparent view and call `layoutIfNeeded` on that view. But then that view will be blocking touches behind it when the blur area is hidden.

CODE:

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let showMenubar = UISwitch()
    let showMenubarBlur = UISwitch()
    let menubarContainer = MenubarContainer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
                
        view.addSubview(menubarContainer)
        menubarContainer.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.left.top.right.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        showMenubar.isOn = true
        showMenubar.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchedMenubar(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
        view.addSubview(showMenubar)
        showMenubar.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.center.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        showMenubarBlur.isOn = true
        showMenubarBlur.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchedMenubarBlur(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
        view.addSubview(showMenubarBlur)
        showMenubarBlur.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
            make.top.equalTo(showMenubar.snp.bottom).offset(100)
        }
        
    }

    @objc func switchedMenubar(sender : UISwitch) {
        menubarContainer.showOrHide(show: sender.isOn)
    }
    
    @objc func switchedMenubarBlur(sender : UISwitch) {
        menubarContainer.showOrHideBlur(show: sender.isOn)
    }

}

class MenubarContainer: UIView {
    
    private let buttonAndSeparatorContainer = UIView()
    private let separator = UIView()
    private let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .dark))
    private var topConstraint : Constraint?
    private let heightOfMenubar = 45.0
    private let separatorHeight = 1.0 / UIScreen.main.scale
    private let duration = TimeInterval(10)
    
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        
        addSubview(blurView)
        blurView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        buttonAndSeparatorContainer.backgroundColor = .systemBlue.withAlphaComponent(0.1)
        
        addSubview(buttonAndSeparatorContainer)
        buttonAndSeparatorContainer.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.left.right.bottom.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(heightOfMenubar)
            topConstraint = make.top.equalTo(safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.top).constraint
        }
        
        separator.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        buttonAndSeparatorContainer.addSubview(separator)
        separator.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.left.right.bottom.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(separatorHeight)
            
        }
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func showOrHide(show : Bool){
        topConstraint?.update(inset: show ? 0 : -heightOfMenubar)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction, .beginFromCurrentState], animations: {
            self.buttonAndSeparatorContainer.alpha = show ? 1 : 0
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
    
    func showOrHideBlur(show : Bool){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction, .beginFromCurrentState], animations: {
            self.blurView.alpha = show ? 1 : 0
            self.separator.alpha = self.blurView.alpha
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: *"calling `layoutIfNeeded` on the `superview` seems to be wasteful as that would layout the entire view controller's view"* -- UIKit will walk the view hierarchy and update the layout of the view and its subviews ***only if needed***. A huge benefit of the auto-layout system is that we don't have to manage that ourselves.